# BeautifulSoup, how can I get texts without class identifier?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

While crawling the website, there is no class name of some text I want to pull or any id style to separate the part that contains that text. In the selector path I used with soup.select it doesn't work for continuous operations. As an example, I want to take the data below, but I don't know how to do it.

[ex.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lwrs.png)

[image: ex2]

Comment: hello again,  ı try to get infos about football players in this website (https://www.transfermarkt.com.tr/altay-bayindir/profil/spieler/336077). like "position", "name", "team". But I can't find appropriate path to my soup.findAll command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess you can get the table, if so and you know the row, you can do the following. Use `findAll` to get all the rows in a list and use the `slice syntax` to access your element:

```
row = your_table_result.findAll('tr')[5::6]
```

**EDITED AFTER QUESTION UPDATE**

You solve your problem in different ways, but first grab the table:

```
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"auflistung"})
```

**Way #1** - You know the row, where information is stored
(be aware that structure of table can change or maybe differ)

```
rows = table.findAll('td')

name = rows[0].text.strip()
position = rows[6].text.strip()
```

**Way #2** - You know heading of information
(works great cause there ist only one column)

```
name = table.find("th", text="Anavatandaki isim:").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
position = table.find("th", text="Mevki:").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
```